# override startOfDay from date-fns

Tags: angular

I want to override the function `date-fns` before any other module will use it.

For example :

```
function startOfDay (dirtyDate) {
  var date = parse(dirtyDate)
  date.setHours(7, 0, 0, 0)
  return date
}
```

How can I do it?

I'm working with angular2.

Comment: I'm having problems understanding what you want to achieved and what is going wrong. Try to further explain your goal and the issue please :)

Comment: I have a module that using this function, to get the start of the day.I wont to that the start of day start on 7, instead of 24.